# Список подключенных устройств к Android

Tags: android, wifi

Подскажите API, выводящий список подключенных устройств к Android устройству в режиме WiFi точки доступа.

Comment: @KoliK, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем вы видите проблему, как ее воспроизвести и т. д.

Comment: [List connected devices to Android phone working as WiFi Access point][1].

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16998095/list-connected-devices-to-android-phone-working-as-wifi-access-point